Handling Multiple Action Owners in Edit Form with Grouping and Dynamic Updates using Laravel
In my Laravel application, I have a table called actions with a column action_owners (id). Previously, each action had only one action_owner. Now, I need to allow multiple action owners for each action.
To implement this, I added a multiple attribute to the select tag in my Create Action form, which creates multiple rows with the same data for each action using a for loop in my controller. The only difference between each row when created is the action_owner value. Each entry also has a unique ID in the action_group_id column to group the same actions together.
Now, I need to create an edit form for this. When submitting the edit form, I want to be able to select multiple action owners again, but only keep the ones that are selected. If any action owners are unselected, I want those corresponding actions to be deleted from the database. Additionally, I want to update the data for the actions that are being modified and create new rows for any newly assigned action owners.
How can I achieve this in Laravel?
Frontend code:
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="action-owner" class="text-bold">Action Owner</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" name="action_owners[]" class="form-control select2" id="action-owner">
    </select>
</div>

Controller code:
public function add_observation()
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $action_title = $_POST['action_title'];

            $group_uid = Str::uuid();

            foreach ($_POST['action_owners'] as $action_owner_id) {
                $ObjDetails = new ObservationDetails;
                $ObjDetails->action_title = $action_title;
                $ObjDetails->action_owner = $action_owner_id;
                $ObjDetails->action_group_id = $group_uid;

                $ObjDetails->save();
            }

            DB::commit();

            echo ('Successful. An email will be sent soon.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            echo ('Create Action Not Successful');
        }
    }

Update schema code:
    Schema::table('audit_observation_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('action_group_id')->nullable()->after('action_owner');
    });


Just create a pivot table between actions and users? Each row in the pivot table then designates an “action owner”. Add a row to add an owner to an action. Remove a row to remove an owner from an action.

please provide a sample of you request data, and post code of what you have tried so far

My senior engineers won't let me create any additional tables. I have to use GROUP BY to do the task

@krisgjika added the sample codes

@PavelRahman if the answer was useful mark it as so

@krisgjika I don't have enough rep to mark it as useful.

it's not very clear from your form, but I assume you send the group ID as part of your POST route in order to identify what is being updated. So in your controller you would have something like this:
public function update_observation(Request $request, $group_id)
{
  // validation
  ...

  try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    // delete any action not present in the action_owners list
    $actions = Action::query()
      ->where('action_group_id', $group_id)
      ->whereNotIn('action_owner', $request->input('action_owners', []))
      ->each(fn (Action $unSelectedAction) => $unSelectedAction->delete());

    // create or update existing actions
    foreach ($request->input('action_owners', []) as $action_owner) {
      // update action title if exists, or create a new action for this owner if not
      Action::query()->updateOrCreate([
          'action_owner' => $action_owner,
          'action_group_id' => $group_id,
        ], [
          'action_title' => $request->input('action_title'),
        ]);
    }

    DB::commit();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
  }
}


I am marking this as the accepted answer as this was the closest that I could come up with for my solution. I had to keep the update and create in separate if else conditions instead of using updateOrCreate() for my own use case.
